# How can I get column types width MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql

how can I get text description for column types with MySQLdb?

I know that `cursor.description` contains number which represents type of column
and also there is module `FIELD_TYPE.*` with int constants like `FIELD_TYPE.ENUM=247`

For example how can I get name of column type if I know that it is '3'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read here for the list of column types:

http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE-module.html

and then create a dictionary from the provided list:

```
field_type = {
 0: 'DECIMAL',
 1: 'TINY',
 2: 'SHORT',
 3: 'LONG',
 4: 'FLOAT',
 5: 'DOUBLE',
 6: 'NULL',
 7: 'TIMESTAMP',
 8: 'LONGLONG',
 9: 'INT24',
 10: 'DATE',
 11: 'TIME',
 12: 'DATETIME',
 13: 'YEAR',
 14: 'NEWDATE',
 15: 'VARCHAR',
 16: 'BIT',
 246: 'NEWDECIMAL',
 247: 'INTERVAL',
 248: 'SET',
 249: 'TINY_BLOB',
 250: 'MEDIUM_BLOB',
 251: 'LONG_BLOB',
 252: 'BLOB',
 253: 'VAR_STRING',
 254: 'STRING',
 255: 'GEOMETRY' }
```

Answer (score 2):

mysql.connector has this information available in the get_info() method of FieldType:

```
import mysql.connector    
from mysql.connector import FieldType

...
cursor.execute("SELECT emp_no, last_name, hire_date "
               "FROM employees WHERE emp_no = %s", (123,))
for i in range(len(cursor.description)):
  print("Column {}:".format(i+1))
  desc = cursor.description[i]
  print("column_name = {}".format(desc[0]))
  print("type = {} ({})".format(desc[1], FieldType.get_info(desc[1])))
  print("null_ok = {}".format(desc[6]))
  print("column_flags = {}".format(desc[7]))
```

code from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-description.html

Comment: Posting code directly from an external source is sometimes useful when using a small section of code to directly answer a question, but just dumping a bunch of lines and telling the OP to look for his/her answer there -- without explanation -- is not terribly helpful.  (Even less so three years after the question was asked and answered.)

Comment: @dg99 
Sorry you found my answer "not terribly helpful" but the original answer was not what the OP was looking for.  This I could tell by reading their comments and the response  "oh, k sry"  from the first answer's poster.

That's why I answered even though it was three year later.

I clearly called out that the get_info() method of the FieldType gave the information the OP was looking for then provided lines of code from the actual mysql documentation with a link.  That where I learned it so just shared it with the OP.

Stack Overflow has been good to me, just trying to give back

Comment: The accepted answer, however, was apparently what the OP was looking for.  This I could tell by looking at the green checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from information_schema.tables
```

contains everything you wanna know about tables :) .. example output (i used the \G switch for prettier formatting):

```
....
*************************** 87. row ***************************
  TABLE_CATALOG: NULL
   TABLE_SCHEMA: phpmyadmin
     TABLE_NAME: pma_table_coords
     TABLE_TYPE: BASE TABLE
         ENGINE: MyISAM
        VERSION: 10
     ROW_FORMAT: Dynamic
     TABLE_ROWS: 29
 AVG_ROW_LENGTH: 39
    DATA_LENGTH: 1156
MAX_DATA_LENGTH: 281474976710655
   INDEX_LENGTH: 4096
      DATA_FREE: 0
 AUTO_INCREMENT: NULL
    CREATE_TIME: 2010-02-09 11:19:59
    UPDATE_TIME: 2010-08-15 19:21:37
     CHECK_TIME: 2010-08-16 18:34:18
TABLE_COLLATION: utf8_bin
       CHECKSUM: NULL
 CREATE_OPTIONS: 
  TABLE_COMMENT: Table coordinates for phpMyAdmin PDF output
...
```

`SHOW COLUMNS FROM table;` displays everything you wanna know about columsn...

```
mysql> show columns from pma_designer_coords;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| db_name    | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| table_name | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| x          | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| y          | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| v          | tinyint(4)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| h          | tinyint(4)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: My question is about python module MySQLdb API. I know that I can query Db, that is not what I need (I mean, MySQLdb's `cursor` already has this information but I dont know how to get it b\c api documentation is not clear).

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using `dir()` and this module really should be fixed (use an enumeration) but at least don't repeat stuff.

```
import m

name_to_value = {
    k: getattr(m, k)
    for k in dir(m)
    if k.isupper()
}

value_to_name = {
    v: k
    for k, v in name_to_value.items()
}

print(value_to_name[42])
```

https://repl.it/@altendky/CruelSnoopyCharactercode